# how to enter in binary search tree by using command line

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am student and I am beginner at C.
I want to make binary search tree by using command line.
I want to enter the number composing BTS by using command line.
I have to make it by using pointer and print it by using preorder.
I delete some code because it's too much code in this question.(delete part)
how to make it?
I can't know how to make main part.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data; //정수를 보관할 노드
    struct node *left_child; // 왼쪽 자식
    struct node *right_child; // 오른쪽 자식
};

struct node* search(struct node *root, int x)
{
    if (root=NULL || root->data==x) // root가 없거나 data가 root와 같다면 root를 리턴
        return root;
    else if (x > root->data)
        return search(root->right_child, x);
    else
        return search(root->left_child, x);
}

struct node* find_minimum(struct node *root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(root->left_child != NULL)
        return find_minimum(root->left_child);
    return root;
}

struct node* new_node(int x)
{
    struct node *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->data = x;
    p->left_child = NULL;
    p->right_child = NULL;

    return p;
}

struct node* insert(struct node *root, int x)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return new_node(x);
    else if(x<root->data)
        root->left_child = insert(root->left_child,x);
    else
        root->right_child = insert(root->right_child, x);
    return root;
}

void preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", root->data);
        preorder(root->left_child);
        preorder(root->right_child);
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    int number;
    int num_count = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("%d", &number);
        if (num_count = 0)
        {

            root = new_node(number);
            num_count += 1;
        }
        else
            if(number == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                insert(root, number);

            }

    }
    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (num_count = 0)` is quite different from `if (num_count == 0)` which is probably what you wanted.

Comment: Turn on the warnings: `printf("%d", &number);` is wrong.

Comment: Also, if I want to show the order in `preorder()` I would output from left, centre, right (not centre, left, right).

Comment: Note too that `else if (number == EOF)` does not test for EOF, but tests whether the valid number entered by the user was the same as EOF (usually `-1`).  You should test the return value from`scanf()` to know whether EOF was detected.

Comment: `if(root=NULL || root->data==x)` will assign NULL to `root` and then dereference it, causing a segfault.

Comment: @DavidConrad —  check the operator priority — I think it works slightly differently (but the result is not good).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good call.

Comment: The interpretation of `if (root = NULL || root->data == x)` is `if (root = (NULL || root->data == x))`.  Since NULL is false, the value stored in `root` is either `0` (NULL) if `root->data != x` or `1` if `root->data == x`.  Neither is a valid pointer.  Clearly, the condition is supposed to be `if (root == NULL || root->data == x)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The test `if (root=NULL || root->data==x)` is incorrect: `=` is the assignment operator, very different from the comparison operator `==`. Use `if (root == NULL || root->data == x)`
- `&number` is the address of variable `number`. Passing the address is required for `scanf()` to store the converted value into the destination object, but you should just pass the value to `printf`, without the `&` operator.
- `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. Testing `if (number == EOF)` is surprising, you should test `if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1)` and possibly `if (number < 0)` if entering a negative number means end of input.
- `printf("%d", root->data);` outputs just the digits, without any extra space or newline, causing all output to appear as a single string of digits. Add spaces and newlines to make the output more readable.
- there is no need to special case the first node: initializing `root` as `NULL` and using `root = insert(root, number);` for each node is safer as it allows for an empty tree.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data; //정수를 보관할 노드
    struct node *left_child; // 왼쪽 자식
    struct node *right_child; // 오른쪽 자식
};

struct node *search(struct node *root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL || root->data == x) // root가 없거나 data가 root와 같다면 root를 리턴
        return root;
    else
    if (x > root->data)
        return search(root->right_child, x);
    else
        return search(root->left_child, x);
}

struct node *find_minimum(struct node *root) {
    if (root != NULL && root->left_child != NULL)
        return find_minimum(root->left_child);
    else
        return root;
}

struct node *new_node(int x) {
    struct node *p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (p != NULL) {
        p->data = x;
        p->left_child = NULL;
        p->right_child = NULL;
    }
    return p;
}

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return new_node(x);
    else if (x < root->data)
        root->left_child = insert(root->left_child, x);
    else
        root->right_child = insert(root->right_child, x);
    return root;
}

void preorder(struct node *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        preorder(root->left_child);
        preorder(root->right_child);
    }
}

void free_tree(struct node *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        free_tree(root->left_child);
        free_tree(root->right_child);
        free(root);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *root = NULL;
    int number;
    while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number >= 0) {
        printf("%d\n", number);
        root = insert(root, number);
    }
    preorder(root);
    printf("\n");
    free_tree(root);
    return 0;
}
```